# Using Volume Shadow Copy to Identify Updated Files

Tags: windows, filesystems, files, vss

I have folders in my server with over 60GBs of data across ~160,000+ files. The files in this folder change regularly. I need to be able to make a backup copy of the files in this folder at a given point in time. Later, after updates have been made, I need to be able to only copy the updated/new files within these folders.

Is is possible to use the Volume Snapshot Service to identify modified files in a drive/folder ?

Comment: Why don't you use backup software to do this, that is what backup software does after all.

Comment: Makes sense, however, the first backup takes over 14 hours and the second run of backup using incremental still takes over an hour or more and restoring it will require a full followed by all it's incrementals and can be slow. I was wondering to see if there was something quicker analogous to differencing disks where I can isolate changes and apply.

Answer (score 0):

I would doubt it, only because it runs on a schedule, not continuously checking files.  What if a file gets updated 10x and then deleted in between the VSS schedule?  I don't think VSS would know about it.

But for copying updated/new files, you can use multiple tools such as robocopy (which only grabs the new/changed files anyway), or do an incremental or differential backup with a backup utility.

Comment: Understood. Robocopy and Windows Backup were still slow (see reply comment to joeqwerty on question). Was hoping there was something faster. I'm testing out a few options and I'll let post what worked best, thanks for the reply.

Comment: What's the end goal?  You seem to want to be able to keep the updated/newer files, but for what?  If it's accidental change/deletion you can setup your VSS schedule to take hourly snapshots if that's what you need.  It won't copy them over to a new drive/server but it will get you decent RPO.  Maybe if you state your end goal in mind we could point you in the right direction.